# Python + cx_Freeze: Unable to locate initialization module

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using [Python 3.4 64-bit](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/) and the corresponding [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) version. This simple hello world does not work correctly as a built executable.

The message from the exe is: Unable to locate initialization module. What could be the issue?

**main.py**

```
print("Hello World")
```

**setup.py**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit'
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='simple_Script',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze script',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

Comment: cx_Freeze hasn't been updated for Python 3.4 yet. You'll need to freeze with Python 3.3 until there's a new release of it.

Comment: There is a Python 3.4 installer on the home page.

Comment: I know - I think it was working with some of the betas. I've asked Anthony to take the link down.